# Is there any closed form for riemenn zeta function for real domain?

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

I wonder if there is any closed form for the riemann zeta function at real domain (eaither including 1 or not)? So at only real values of s, does the zeta function have a closed form?

I would be grateful if you also answer this similar question: does the zeta function have a closed form at imaginary domain? (and by imaginary I don't mean complex obviously).

EDIT: the real domain doesn't need to include all real numbers, but at least the number 0.5 should be included.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "closed form," but probably not. (Most functions you'd think of as being a "closed form" admit an analytic continuation with much simpler properties than the Riemann zeta function.)

Comment: Everything that we can do with $\zeta(s)$ is in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis and so on

Comment: @reuns thank you I can see there is one integral form for real values more than 1 but I cannot find out if there is one including 0.5 as well or not.